# BinanceAPIExceptionError: APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client, python-binance

I tried every solution on the Internet in order to get rid of this error message but for some reason I can't solve it.

```
client = Client(api_key=api_key, api_secret=secret_key, tld="com")
pd.DataFrame()
print(client)
print(time.time())
client.get_account()
```

This is the code on PyCharm.

I have enabled Futures, Spot and Margin Trading as well. My API key and secret key is also correct. If anyone had also experienced this please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist your IP address on your API key page in 'IP access restrictions' rubric.